# Inserting data into SQL table is showing error

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database

I am trying to store my array data into the SQL table but it is throwing me an error every time. I don't really know how to solve it and fix the issue

I already tried to insert the values differently and separately but it is still not working. I am extracting the data from MS Word and then putting it into an array before passing it to my SQL table

```
SqlConnection sc = new SqlConnection();
SqlCommand sm = new SqlCommand();
sc.ConnectionString = "server = ASIR\\SQLEXPRESS; database = elawdb; uid = Asir/Dip; Integrated Security=True";
sc.Open();
string query = "INSERT INTO Reference_form (DATAFILENAME, ACTFILENAME, ACTTITLE,FORMNUMBER, FORMTITLE, SECTIONREFERENCE, BOOLEANTEXT, COUNTRY)";
query += " VALUES (" + db[0] + "," + db[1] + "," + db[2] + "," + db[3] + "," + db[4] + "," + db[5] + "," + db[6] + "," + db[7] +" )";

SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(query, sc);
//}
myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

//       myinfo.Text = "connection to db is made";
sc.Close();
doc.Close();
word.Quit();
```

The error I get is:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll Incorrect syntax near ','. 'out' is not a
>   recognized SET option.

Comment: Probably you have to put your values into quotes.

Comment: Better yet, use parameters [instead of string concatenation](https://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: Do share your table design so that one can match the datatypes.

Comment: Table design : 
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Reference_form](
    [DATAFILENAME] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [ACTFILENAME] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ACTTITLE] [varchar](2550) NULL,
    [FORMNUMBER] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [FORMTITLE] [varchar](2000) NULL,
    [SECTIONREFERENCE] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [BOOLEANTEXT] [text] NULL,
    [COUNTRY] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Counting] [bit] NULL,

Comment: or use an ORM like dapper. Here your issue is one of those field got a space ` `, comma `,` and need the singlequote escaping around the string.

Comment: Replace your query string with this: "INSERT INTO [dbo].[Reference_form] ([DATAFILENAME] ,[ACTFILENAME] ,[ACTTITLE] ,[FORMNUMBER] ,[FORMTITLE] ,[SECTIONREFERENCE] ,[BOOLEANTEXT] ,[COUNTRY] ,[Counting]) VALUES ('" + db[0] + "' ,'" + db[1] + "' ,'" + db[2] + "' ,'" + db[3] + "' ,'" + db[4] + "' ,'" + db[5] + "' ,'" + db[6] + "', " + db[7] + ")"

Comment: please don't use string concatenation in your SQL queries because of SQL Injection. Using parameters also easy to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The immediate problem is that you are concatenating strings into you SQL code without enclosing them in apostrophes. When the query is executed, Sql Server finds something that looks like SQL code instead of strings that should be inserted.

But it is ***bad practise*** to build a query by concatenating the field values like you are currently doing. It can open up the possibility of [Sql injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), which in turn can lead to data leaks or data loss. **Now** is the time for you to learn to use parameters instead of concatenating data into the Sql code.

Here is (an untested) version of the SQL part of your code:

```
using (SqlConnection sc = new SqlConnection())
using (SqlCommand sm = new SqlCommand())
{
    sc.ConnectionString = "server = ASIR\\SQLEXPRESS; database = elawdb; uid = Asir/Dip; Integrated Security=True";
    sc.Open();
    sm.CommandText = @"
        INSERT INTO Reference_form (DATAFILENAME, ACTFILENAME, ACTTITLE, FORMNUMBER, FORMTITLE, SECTIONREFERENCE, BOOLEANTEXT, COUNTRY)
        VALUES (@DATAFILENAME, @ACTFILENAME, @ACTTITLE, @FORMNUMBER, @FORMTITLE, @SECTIONREFERENCE, @BOOLEANTEXT, @COUNTRY)
    ";
    sm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DATAFILENAME", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = db[0];
    sm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ACTFILENAME", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = db[1];
    sm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ACTTITLE", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = db[2];
    sm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FORMNUMBER", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = db[3];
    sm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FORMTITLE", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = db[4];
    sm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@SECTIONREFERENCE", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = db[5];
    sm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@BOOLEANTEXT", System.Data.SqlDbType.Text)).Value = db[6];
    sm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@COUNTRY", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = db[7];
    sm.Connection = sc;
    sm.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since C# 6 you can use string interpolation which makes your sql command more readable.

```
string query = $"INSERT INTO Reference_form (DATAFILENAME, ACTFILENAME, ACTTITLE,FORMNUMBER, FORMTITLE, SECTIONREFERENCE, BOOLEANTEXT, COUNTRY) VALUES ('{db[0]}', '{db[1]}', .......)";
```

If you want a more detailed answer you have to show us your table and sql insert command with sample values

Comment: How is it a different answer from the ones mentioned in comments already?

Comment: Also the asking user has already shared the schema in the comments.

Comment: It's an other way to build a sql command string, but the best are sure parameters. And yes I am sorry, I forgot to look at the comments